# DropDown Flyout with JSON content

Tags: javascript, json

Using JQuery How can i call JSON on mouse hover of the Link lets say I have Main DIV says

```
<div class="mainnav">
   <UL>
    <li id="mainnav1">Movie</li>
    <li id="mainnav2">Drama</li>
    <li id="mainnav3">trailer</li>
   </UL>
 </div>
```

on mouse over of `Movie` wanted to display `subnav`

```
  <div class="subnav">
   <Ul>
    <h3><a href="/comady.html">Comady</a></h3>
    <li><a href="/movies/KungFuDunk">KungFu Dunk</a></li>
    <li><a href="/movies/IntimateAffairs">Intimate Affairs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/movies//movies/HighHopes">High Hopes</a></li>
   </UL>
   <UL>
    <h3><a href="/classics.html">Classics</a></h3>
    <li><a href="/movies/TheWomanWhoCameBack">The Woman Who Came Back</a></li>
    <li><a href="/movies/TheNorthStar">The North Star</a></li>
  </UL>
```

I can do this with Static content, but What I wanted to do is whatever there in DIV `subnav` would be a dynamic so I have written JSON some thing like this

```
   [ {    "catogoryName" : "Movie",
    "productGroupInformationList" : [ { "groupName" : "comady",
          "link" : "/comady.html",
          "productsInformationList" : [ { "productLink" : "/movies/KungFuDunk",
                "productTitle" : "Kung Fu Dunk"
              },
              { "productLink" : "/movies/IntimateAffairs",
                "productTitle" : "Intimate Affairs"
              },
              { "productLink" : "/movies/HighHopes",
                "productTitle" : "High Hopes"
              }
            ]
        },
        { "groupName" : "Classics",
          "link" : "/classics.html",
          "productsInformationList" : [ { "productLink" : "/movies/TheWomanWhoCameBack",
                "productTitle" : "The Woman Who Came Back"
              },
              { "productLink" : "/movies/TheNorthStar",
                "productTitle" : "The North Star"
              }
            ]
        }
      ]
  } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this jQuery Code,

```
    var jsn = [ {    "catogoryName" : "Movie",
        "productGroupInformationList" : [ { "groupName" : "comady",
            "link" : "/comady.html",
            "productsInformationList" : [ { "productLink" : "/movies/KungFuDunk",
                  "productTitle" : "Kung Fu Dunk"
                },
                { "productLink" : "/movies/IntimateAffairs",
                  "productTitle" : "Intimate Affairs"
                },
                { "productLink" : "/movies/HighHopes",
                  "productTitle" : "High Hopes"
                }
              ]
          },
          { "groupName" : "Classics",
            "link" : "/classics.html",
            "productsInformationList" : [ { "productLink" : "/movies/TheWomanWhoCameBack",
                  "productTitle" : "The Woman Who Came Back"
                },
                { "productLink" : "/movies/TheNorthStar",
                  "productTitle" : "The North Star"
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
    } ];

 $("#mainnav1").hover(function(data) {
    for(var i in jsn)  {
        //alert( jsn[i].catogoryName);
        document.write(jsn[i].catogoryName + '<br>');
        var l2cnt = jsn[i].productGroupInformationList.length;
        for(var l2=0; l2<l2cnt; l2++ )  {
           document.write(jsn[i].productGroupInformationList[l2].groupName + '<br>');                                document.write(jsn[i].productGroupInformationList[l2].link + '<br>');
 var l3cnt =jsn[i].productGroupInformationList[l2].productsInformationList.length;
            for(var l3=0; l3<l3cnt; l3++)  {
                                   document.write(jsn[i].productGroupInformationList[l2].productsInformationList[l3].productLink + '<br>');
      document.write(jsn[i].productGroupInformationList[l2].productsInformationList[l3].productTitle + '<br>');
            }

        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Robin Michael Poothurai... somehow im not getting `productGroupInformationList`  details... here is my working example [ http://jsfiddle.net/Rd6RF/19/ ]

Comment: @user1060990 you mean , it is working fine  and you have completed this task?

Comment: its not working ... for me throws some undefined Error on `productGroupInformationList` can you take a look on [  jsfiddle.net/Rd6RF/19  ]

Comment: @user1060990  I have updated the link,  [ jsfiddle.net/Rd6RF/19 ] verify it. I have worked on Chrome, you can test diff browsers and let me know,  I found in IE9 it will stop after first document write , that works fine when u make ur htmls. all other browsers OK.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) or the similar functionality offered by [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) and [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template). Each will allow you to pass a JSON object to a template to allow the JSON to be rendered into the template.